# how to attach multiple parameter to index.php using rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

hi i am trying to make clean and neat url using rewrite rule
I want to achive :
`abc.com/t/param1/param2`

Rewite rule that I wrote
`RewriteRule   ^t/(.+)/(.+)$   t/index.php?v=$1&t=$2   [L]`

but it doen't work it redirects to :
`http://abc.com/?v=param1&t=param2`

Comment: And what other rules do you have on your htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should only match characters that aren't slashes. So your rule should look like

```
RewriteRule ^t/[^/]+/[^/]+$ t/index.php?v=$1&t=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?v=$1&t=$2 [L]`